# Parse / Angular web app - how to protect source

Tags: angularjs, security, web-applications, parse-platform

I am developing an web app using Parse.com and AngularJS, ie in a two tier architecture.

My question is, how would I protect the source?  Wouldn't anyone could completely copied my static files and clone the site?

Thanks guys

Comment: I think it cant be avoided. You can make it harder with uglify etc.

Answer (score 1):

That is basically what you have to deal with when leveraging client-side javascript.  You can certainly use an obfuscating minifier for your final downloadable file to make trying to reverse engineer it a little more difficult, but still there is no getting around the fact that you have a working open source file out there.